# How to publish a git repo via HTTP using nginx?

Tags: centos, git, nginx

I've a CentOS 5 server at domain.fr. I am trying to set a subdomain so that I can use it with git : git.domain.fr

My repositories are in /home/git (example /home/git/repos.git)

I've installed `git-http-backend` and Nginx. I've set a repository like this:

```
cd /home/git/repos.git && git --bare init
```

I've set my `git.conf` (included in `nginx.conf`) as below.

However, on my client shell, I get the fatal error "repository not found": `git clone http://git.domain.fr/repos.git`

Does anyone know what I should do? It seems so simple, I'm getting frustrated because I'm sure it's nothing.

```
server {

    listen          80;
    server_name     git.domain.fr;
    root            /home/git;

    location ~ /(/.*) {

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/bin/git-http-backend;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL     true;
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT        /home/git;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this snippet in a SO Q&A titled: [How to serve GIT through HTTP via NGINX with user/password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414227/how-to-serve-git-through-http-via-nginx-with-user-password).

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  git.mydomain.com;

        location ~ /git(/.*) {
            # fcgiwrap is set up to listen on this host:port
            fastcgi_pass  localhost:9001;
            include       fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
            # export all repositories under GIT_PROJECT_ROOT
            fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
            fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT    /srv/git;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO           $1;
        }
    }
}
```

I would make sure that your setup mirrors this one as much as possible. Also since I believe Apache is accessing your `/home/git` directory you need to take care that this user is able to do so. Additionally if you're using SELinux you need to make sure that the process (httpd) has appropriate contexts added to `/home` so that it's able to access this directory too.

Consult your `/var/log/httpd/error_log` log file for more details on where Apache is getting tripped up.

Comment: Hi ! I already checked this, but it won't work on my config. I can not figure out why, It changes nothing. Where can I find helpful logs ? What methodology/steps should I follow to debug this ?
Thanks !

Comment: @Charaf - as I stated before, the log file I'd like to see first is this one: `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Comment: Almost there ! I removed the regex and replaced the fastcgi_pass url according to this post : http://superuser.com/questions/719949/centos-5-nginx-git-http-backend/720203?noredirect=1#720203

I do not have errors in the error_log anymore, but is still get a HTTP 502 when I git clone.

iMac-de-Charaf:tmp charaf$ git clone http://git.domain.fr/repos.git
Cloning into 'repos'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.domain.fr/repos.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502

Comment: The post is continued here : http://superuser.com/questions/719949/centos-5-nginx-git-http-backend

Comment: @Charaf - you should've just kept the post here. Cross posting is discouraged and typically leads to Q's getting closed.

Comment: I am sorry. It's just because, at the begining, I posted it in the two places because I wasn't sure were to do so. Then, alexeyten gave me a really helping reply and I had to give him updates.
I won't do this mistake again. Sorry.

Comment: @Charaf - I saw that, that's why we didn't close your Q, just wanted to make you aware. No harm just a friendly FYI.

Comment: I solved it on the other topic, finally =)
Thanks a lot !

Comment: In case you're curious, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40313590/107158 illustrates how to configure `git-http-backend` to enable  *anonymous read access but authenticated write access*.